# How can we drop an ID based on the distinct value associated in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I have an id and an event.
I want to drop all rows of this `ID` when you have only one specific `EVENT` possible : `NIF`.

In the next example, the `id_2` should be drop.

```
dff = spark.createDataFrame([
('id_1','ST'),('id_1','ST'),('id_1','ST'),('id_1','ST'),('id_1','NIF'),('id_1','ST'),('id_1','SB'),
('id_2','NIF'),('id_2','NIF'),('id_2','NIF'),('id_2','NIF'),('id_2','NIF'),('id_2','NIF'),('id_2','NIF'),
('id_3','AB'),('id_3','NIF'),('id_3','DR'),('id_3','NIF'),('id_3','ST'),('id_3','NIF'),('id_3','DS'),
('id_4','AB'),('id_4','AB'),('id_4','AB'),('id_4','AB'),('id_4','AB'),('id_4','AB'),('id_4','AB') 
],['ID','EVENT'])

display(dff)
```

I tryied with `distinct()` but I'm not sure how I could deal with it in order to remove these `ID` from my dataframe.

```
> dff.select('ID','EVENT').distinct().show()

+----+-----+
|  ID|EVENT|
+----+-----+
|id_1|   ST|
|id_2|  NIF|
|id_1|   SB|
|id_3|  NIF|
|id_3|   DR|
|id_4|   AB|
|id_1|  NIF|
|id_3|   AB|
|id_3|   ST|
|id_3|   DS|
+----+-----+
```

What would be the best way (in terms of computation/parallelization) to do it ?

EDIT ---
I found the solution :

```
dff = dff.withColumn('test', f.when((f.size(f.collect_set(f.col("EVENT")).over(Window().partitionBy('ID').orderBy('ID')))==1) & (f.col("EVENT")=="NIF"), 1).otherwise(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself :

Creating a column based on the size of each ID (taking the unique element for each) : if you have a unique element and this one is `NIF` then the `test` variable will be 1 otherwise 0.

```
dff = dff.withColumn('test', f.when((f.size(f.collect_set(f.col("EVENT")).over(Window().partitionBy('ID').orderBy('ID')))==1) & (f.col("EVENT")=="NIF"), 1).otherwise(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC - You do not want **NIF** in the **event** column

```
df = df.filter(~(F.col("EVENT") == F.lit("NIF")))
df.show()
+----+-----+
|  ID|EVENT|
+----+-----+
|id_1|   ST|
|id_1|   ST|
|id_1|   ST|
|id_1|   ST|
|id_1|   ST|
|id_1|   SB|
|id_3|   AB|
|id_3|   DR|
|id_3|   ST|
|id_3|   DS|
|id_4|   AB|
|id_4|   AB|
|id_4|   AB|
|id_4|   AB|
|id_4|   AB|
|id_4|   AB|
|id_4|   AB|
+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on course. Going by your output above, see code below

```
h=Window.partitionBy('ID')
dff.select('ID','EVENT').distinct().withColumn('count',count('ID').over(h)).filter(col('count')!=1).drop('count').show()

+----+-----+
|  ID|EVENT|
+----+-----+
|id_1|   ST|
|id_1|  NIF|
|id_1|   SB|
|id_3|   AB|
|id_3|  NIF|
|id_3|   DR|
|id_3|   ST|
|id_3|   DS|
+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the occurence of NIF and compare with the number of event :

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

w = W.partitionBy("id")

dff = dff.withColumn(
    "count_niff", F.sum(F.when(F.col("EVENT") == "NIF", 1)).over(w)
).withColumn("count_event", F.count("*").over(w))

dff.show()

+----+-----+----------+-----------+
|  ID|EVENT|count_niff|count_event|
+----+-----+----------+-----------+
|id_2|  NIF|         7|          7|
|id_2|  NIF|         7|          7|
|id_2|  NIF|         7|          7|
|id_2|  NIF|         7|          7|
|id_2|  NIF|         7|          7|
|id_2|  NIF|         7|          7|
|id_2|  NIF|         7|          7|
|id_4|   AB|      null|          7|
|id_4|   AB|      null|          7|
|id_4|   AB|      null|          7|
|id_4|   AB|      null|          7|
|id_4|   AB|      null|          7|
|id_4|   AB|      null|          7|
|id_4|   AB|      null|          7|
|id_1|   ST|         1|          7|
|id_1|   ST|         1|          7|
|id_1|   ST|         1|          7|
|id_1|   ST|         1|          7|
|id_1|  NIF|         1|          7|
|id_1|   ST|         1|          7|
|id_1|   SB|         1|          7|
|id_3|   AB|         3|          7|
|id_3|  NIF|         3|          7|
|id_3|   DR|         3|          7|
|id_3|  NIF|         3|          7|
|id_3|   ST|         3|          7|
|id_3|  NIF|         3|          7|
|id_3|   DS|         3|          7|
+----+-----+----------+-----------+
```

You can remove the lines where `count_niff == count_event`.